# Am I allowed to pass an integer pointer to a function that takes an integer array as an argument in c++?

Tags: c++

Probably a stupid question to ask, but seeing as how I'm new here, and this question has to do with a project I'm working one, I'm sure it wouldn't hurt to ask. Many thanks to whosoever answers.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the type of the parameter.

```
void function(int param[]);   //you can pass a int*
void function(int param[7]);   //you can pass a int*
void function(int (&param)[7]);   //you CANNOT pass a int*
```

Comment: Thank you very much, internet person. I knew of the relation between arrays and pointers, I just wasn't sure of the legality of what I was doing.

Comment: Irritatingly, you can pass _any_ `int*` to the first two, even if they point to a `int[100]`, `int[2]`, or even `NULL`!

Answer (score 1):

An array parameter, e.g. `int arr[]`, is <strike>essentially</strike> the same as a pointer to the first element. So pass the pointer to the integer and a length of 1, and you can make a single integer appear just like an array.

Comment: Strike "essentially". It *is* the same. The compiler rewrites array arguments to pointer arguments.

Answer (score 0):

No function takes array as an argument in c++, arrays decay to pointers, so yes, it's the same thing more or less here.

Comment: Not true, you can take array by reference, it doesn't decay then.

Comment: `template<int len> void function(int (&array)[len]);`  Although, technically, that's by reference, which isn't _technically_ the same...

Comment: You're taking a reference to array, then. Not an array.